# swagger-codegen-maven-plugin 2.3.1 generate response custom object but not in 3.0.0

Tags: java, maven, swagger

swagger-codegen-maven-plugin 2.3.1 generate a java objet:

```
public InlineResponse2005 loginJsonapiPost(Auth auth) throws RestClientException { ...

public class InlineResponse2005 {
  @JsonProperty("data")
  private User data = null;
  @JsonProperty("meta")
  private Object meta = null;
  @JsonProperty("links")
  private Object links = null;
  @JsonProperty("errors")
  private Errors errors = null;
  ...
}
```

but swagger-codegen-maven-plugin 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT **NOT** generate a java objet and return Object object:

```
public Object loginJsonapiPost(Object body) throws RestClientException { ...
```

**My swagger file:**

```
"/login.jsonapi": {
      "post": {
        "summary": "Create a session",
        "tags": [
          "Users"
        ],
        "consumes": [
          "application/json"
        ],
        "description": "      Authenticate a user with her/his email and password and return an\n      access token suitable for authentication.\n",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "auth",
            "in": "body",
            "schema": {
              "type": "object",
              "properties": {
                "email": {
                  "type": "string"
                },
                "password": {
                  "type": "string"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Returning",
            "schema": {
              "type": "object",
              "properties": {
                "data": {
                  "$ref": "#/definitions/user"
                },
                "meta": {
                  "type": "object"
                },
                "links": {
                  "type": "object"
                },
                "errors": {
                  "$ref": "#/definitions/errors"
                }
              },
              "required": [
                "data"
              ]
            }
          },
          "422": {
            "description": "Returning",
            "schema": {
              "type": "object",
              "properties": {
                "errors": {
                  "$ref": "#/definitions/errors"
                }
              },
              "required": [
                "errors"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
```

**My response is:**

responses.schema.properties.data "#/definitions/user"

responses.schema.properties.meta "object"

responses.schema.properties.links "object"

responses.schema.properties.errors "#/definitions/errors"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3.0.0-SNAPSHOT have a bug with V2 model. We need use V2.3.1 of swagger-codegen-maven-plugin.

In my case I have 2 models (one V2 and one V3). Son I create a Maven parent with 3 modules (source generator V2, source generator V3 and My project).

I `mvn clean install` on my parent and I do not have issue on my project.